# Go through each column of a dataframe, apply function, and report the function's output from all columns in a single column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to optimize some messy code I have written in the past and create some  functions that can be used to run the same code in multiple dataframes, each with different column names.

The dataframes I am working on have the following structure:

```
  structure(list(  PTM = c(    "AAAS_T27_M1",    "AAK1_T606_M1",    "AAK1_T620_M1",    "AASDH_S649_M1",    "ABCC3_S911_M1",    "ABCC4_S655_M1",    "ABCC4_S665_M2",    "ABCC4_S668_M1",    "ABCC4_S668_M2",    "ABCC4_T646_M1",    "ABCC5_S505_M1",    "ABCC5_S505_M2",    "ABCC5_S509_M1",    "ABCF1_S105_M1",    "ABCF1_S105_M2",    "ABCF1_S109_M1",    "ABCF1_S166_M1",    "ABCF1_T108_M1",    "ABI1_S183_M1",    "ABI2_S183_M1"  ),  logFC_A = c(    NA,    NA,    -0.797823,    1.04461,    NA,    NA,    NA,    NA,    NA,    NA,    NA,    NA,    3.83343,    NA,    -1.37837,    0.943688,    NA,    0.813075,    NA,    0.474918  ),  logFC_B = c(    -0.755209,    0.845812,    -0.435721,    1.60958,    -0.935074,    0.536129,    -1.88669,    1.01129,    -1.31134,    NA,    NA,    -0.680194,    NA,    NA,    NA,    NA,    0.540836,    NA,    0.890831,    0.782319  ),  logFC_C = c(    NA,    NA,    -0.681984,    1.5103,    NA,    0.595031,    -1.62621,    NA,    -1.07332,    0.669169,    0.427444,    NA,    NA,    0.957807,    NA,    NA,    NA,    NA,    0.812133,    0.794539  )))
```

I would like to create an additional column that reports the status of each PTM (positive, negative, or unchanged (NA)) in A, B and C conditions.

The desired output would be something like:
| PTM | A-B-C |
|:---- |:------:|
| AAAS_T27_M1  | Unchanged - Negative - Unchanged    |
| AAK1_T606_M1  | Unchanged - Positive - Unchanged    |

Currently I am doing this by creating a Status column for each condition (A,B and C) and then uniting them.

```
data %>%
 mutate(Status_A = ifelse(is.na(logFC_A),"Unaffected", ifelse(logFC_A <0, "Down","Up"))%>% 
 mutate(Status_B = ifelse(is.na(logFC_B),"Unaffected", ifelse(logFC_B <0, "Down","Up"))%>% 
 mutate(Status_C = ifelse(is.na(logFC_C),"Unaffected", ifelse(logFC_C <0, "Down","Up"))%>%
 unite(A_B_C, Status_A,Status_B,Status_C)
```

However, I have to do this for more than 20 dataframes where each one has unique column names. The dataframes are part of a list, if that plays a role.

Comment: Hi it seems I can't re-create your example dataframe. I get the error: `Error: unexpected '<' in "                                                                                                                                                                                            -20L"`. In addition, have you tried the function `dplyr::across()` to use a funcion on multiple, tidyselected columns of a dataframe? Then you could wrap this procedure in a function and use `purrr::map()` (or `lapply()`) with your list of dataframes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error! I have now updated it and it should work.  dplyr::across() is a good suggestion. I will have a look at it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply()` to apply the function to all columns in the input data (excluding the first one, so use `data[, -1]`). Then use `do.call()` to paste the columns together into 1 column. Finally use `cbind()` to join the first column back in.

```
want <- lapply(data[, -1], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x),"Unaffected", ifelse(x <0, "Down","Up"))) %>% 
    do.call(paste, .) %>% 
    cbind(data[1], combined = .)

head(want)
            PTM                   combined
1   AAAS_T27_M1 Unaffected Down Unaffected
2  AAK1_T606_M1   Unaffected Up Unaffected
3  AAK1_T620_M1             Down Down Down
4 AASDH_S649_M1                   Up Up Up
5 ABCC3_S911_M1 Unaffected Down Unaffected
6 ABCC4_S655_M1           Unaffected Up Up
```

If you need the hypens in the `combined` column then replace `paste` with a custom function to to this.

```
want <- lapply(data[, -1], function(x) ifelse(is.na(x),"Unaffected", ifelse(x <0, "Down","Up"))) %>% 
    do.call(function(...) paste(..., sep=" - "), .) %>% 
    cbind(data[1], combined = .)

head(want)
            PTM                       combined
1   AAAS_T27_M1 Unaffected - Down - Unaffected
2  AAK1_T606_M1   Unaffected - Up - Unaffected
3  AAK1_T620_M1             Down - Down - Down
4 AASDH_S649_M1                   Up - Up - Up
5 ABCC3_S911_M1 Unaffected - Down - Unaffected
6 ABCC4_S655_M1           Unaffected - Up - Up
```